# Using Perl to match all words after a particular word

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Perl and need to get all domain names from http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt into a flat file.

I think the easiest way to do this is to use a regular expression but I can't get my head around how to build the expression.

my code so far:
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use LWP::Simple;

```
$url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt';

$content = get $url;
open(my $fh, '>', '/home/jay/feed.txt');
#logic here
}
close $fh;
```

I'm not sure if I should loop over each line and perform an expression on that or if I should take the whole file as a string and work with that.

Comment: You should always post a short but **complete** script instead of non-working snippets to minimize the work others need to do.

Comment: [Sobrique](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique) has written a solution that attempts to extract the *domain name* from the *host names* in the list, while [Sinan Ünür](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%c3%9cn%c3%bcr) and I have assumed that you just want the second column of data from the file. Which is correct please? I'm not clear how your subject line ***match all words after a particular word*** ties in with your description

Comment: Borodin, I want to get everything after 127.0.0.1 apart from the first line localhost. e.g.

0koryu0.easter.ne.jp
109-204-26-16.netconnexion.managedbroadband.co.uk
11.lamarianella.info

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is just a `text/plain` document, so I think I would just copy and paste the page into my editor and remove the unwanted information. However if you would prefer a Perl program then this is all that is necessary. It uses `LWP::Simple::get` to fetch the text page and a regex to search it for lines starting with digits and dots, returning the second field of each

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::Simple qw/ get /;

my $url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt';
say for get($url) =~ /^[\d.]+\s+(\S+)/gam;
```

or as a one-liner

```
perl -MLWP::Simple=get -E"say for get(shift) =~ /^[\d.]+\s+(\S+)/gam" http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex but it doesn't seem to be working - are you able to help me see what is wrong in it? https://regex101.com/r/kC3sA8/2

Comment: You haven't copied it correctly. You need modifiers `/gam`. What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: V 5.18. I put in /gam in the modifiers section but still not working for me

Comment: @Jamie: I can't tell why it won't work now. It's fine on your regex101with `/gm` (it won't accept `/a`)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a particular need, iterating by line is the way forward. Otherwise you just tie up memory unnecessarily.

However when you're fetching a url, it's a bit academic - I would suggest that fetching it to a file first isn't a bad thing though, so you can re-process it without needing to refetch.

Given source data sample:

```
 for ( split ( "\n", $content ) ) {
      next unless m/^\d/; #skip lines that don't start with a digit. 
      my ( $IP, $hostname ) = split;
      my $domainname = $hostname =~ s/^\w+\.//r;
      print $domainname,"\n";
 }
```

This doesn't entirely work with your list though, because in that list you have a mix of hostnames and domain names, and it's not actually all that easy to tell the difference.

After all, the 'tld' at the end might be `.com` or it might be `.org.it`

Comment: +1 but your `split` increases the memory footprint unnecessarily. Better to read through the string line-by-line using `readline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
127.0.0.1\s+(.*)
```

should work fine with global modifier.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kC3sA8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Unless saving the list file locally is a requirement (in which case you might be better off just using `wget` or `curl`), there is no need to save it in an external file to process it line-by-line.

You can instead open a filehandle to the string itself.

In the script below, `extract_hosts` would work the same whether you give it a reference to a string or a filename:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw( croak );
use LWP::Simple qw( get );

my $url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt';

my $malware_hosts = get $url;
unless (defined $malware_hosts) {
    die "Failed to get content from '$url'\n";
}

my $hosts = extract_hosts(\$malware_hosts);
print "$_\n" for @$hosts;

sub extract_hosts {
    my $src = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $src
        or croak "Failed to open '$src' for reading: $!";

    my @hosts;

    while (my $entry = <$fh>) {
        next unless $entry =~ /\S/;
        next if $entry =~ /^#/;

        my (undef, $host) = split ' ', $entry;
        push @hosts, $host;
    }

    close $fh
        or croak "Failed to close '$src': $!";

    \@hosts;
}
```

This will give you the list of hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Code to grep the hostnames from the given file.

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt';

my $content = get $url;
my @server_names = split(/127\.0\.0\.1\s*/, $content);

open(my $fh, '>', '/home/jay/feed.txt');
print $fh "@server_names";
close $fh;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another implementation. It uses HTML::Tiny which is part of the core so you don't have to install anything.

```
 use HTTP::Tiny;

 my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get('http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt');

 die "Failed!\n" unless $response->{success};
 my @content;

 for my $line ( split ( "\n", $response->{content} ) ){
     next if ( $line =~ /^#|^$/);
     push @content, ((split ( " ", $line ))[1]);
  }

  print Dumper (\@content);
```